# Django manage.py question

Tags: python, django, command-line

Why is it that I have to run `python manage.py somecommand` and others simply run `manage.py somecommand`? I'm on OSX 10.6. Is this because there is a pre-set way to enable `.py` files to automatically run as Python scripts, and I've somehow disabled the functionality, or is that something that you explicitly enable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Django, the manage.py file should be an "executable" file by default.

Please note, you cannot just type `manage.py somecommand` into the terminal as manage.py is not on the PATH, you will have to type ./ before it to run it from the current directory, i.e. `./manage.py somecommand`.

If that does not work please be sure that the manage.py file has:
`#!/usr/bin/env python`
as its first line. And make sure it is executable: `chmod +x manage.py`

Comment: Just to clarify, when you install Django via pip and do _“django-admin.py startproject pancakes”_ the _‘manage.py’_ in the _‘pancakes/’_ directory won't be executable. This is a [bug](http://git.io/o9uHPQ) with **pip**, not Django.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you should look at:

First, is the manage.py script set to be executable? If not, try

```
chmod u+x manage.py
```

Secondly, does manage.py have a valid [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line? If not, you could try adding one that points to the correct python interpreter for your system.

Answer (score 1):

On the mac the manage.py command has to be executable to just run it without the python command. You can do this with:

```
chmod 755 manage.py
```

If you are in the same directory as manage.py, to run it you type:

```
./manage.py somecommand
```

Otherwise you want to specify the path:

```
/path/to/my/project/manage.py somecommand
```